# Python: How to delete and move vertices on multiple objects based on position

Tags: python

I have a grid of objects that each have 2 separate shells in them (cube and sphere)
[image]
What I want to do is delete the mesh in front, which would be all vertices where their Y position is less than 5. And then select the rest of the vertices and move them along the Y axis by -15.

For the deletion part I have found this script in another question:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

ob = bpy.context.object
assert ob.type == "MESH"
mat = ob.matrix_world
me = ob.data

global_z_plane = False

if me.is_editmode:
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
else:
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(me)

for v in bm.verts:
    co = mat * v.co if global_z_plane else v.co
    if co.z < 0:
        bm.verts.remove(v)

if bm.is_wrapped:
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
else:
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    me.update()
```

This seems to work if I change the Z for a Y and the 0 for 5 but only for the selected object. I need it to do it with all objects in a collection with a specific name like 'Collection'.
I've tried grafting together the code from another question I made previously, but I don't really know enough python to make it work.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Sounds like a possible XY problem to me. Why do you need this? What's the actual goal that you want to achieve by deleting them and moving them? What's the context?

Comment: @Martynas Žiemys the grid is the result of merging the spheres to the objects in front of them. The objects are a sort of asset library and have other objects linked to them in the file so when I need to change the meshes in the library but still retain the same names and links the best way I've found is to just merge the new meshes to them and delete the old ones, then move the new one forward. It's not like it takes a lot of time to do it manually but if there's an automatic way that'd be appreciated.

Comment: The code I used to merge them is from this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/300848/python-how-to-merge-objects-in-a-grid-with-the-objects-in-another-grid
but if I try to copy the lines that I think select the objects in the collection it does not work

Comment: Can't you just replace object's data?

Comment: Like if you have Cube and Suzanne `bpy.data.objects["Cube"].data = bpy.data.objects["Suzanne"].data`

Comment: there is a lot of objects in the file and they all have different names and are link to different things. The imported objects also have different names each time depending on what they are. I'm pretty sure the easiest thing to do is merge them like what I am doing. I just need it to do it automatically

Comment: No need to do it by name, you can use a for loop and replace all of the data of objects based on some conditions. Could you describe the original goal a bit better? What do you mean when you say they are linked? Do you mean, their data is linked to other objects or are they linked some other ways? If so, how are they linked?  How do you choose what to replace by what? I think there is an easier way to achieve that without worrying about geometry and merging objects.